# Who gave boon to Vikramaditya to live for 2000 years and why?

Tags: history, vikramaditya

It is said that King Vikramaditya lived for exact 2000 years. How did he managed to live so long? was that a boon from some God? or was it a trick?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Lord Indra** offered with a throne to King Vikramaditya for solving a curious quest of greatest dancer among *Aspsaras* (*Rambha*, *Urvasi*, *Menaka* and *Tilottama*).

[Blog link](http://hindumythologyforgennext.blogspot.in/2012/08/vikramaditya-and-apsaras.html)

> Indra was pleased. He had found someone who could be sent to Kaushika. He turned to Vikramditya, 'King! You may not know it, but you have done a great service for me! In appreciation of this I will give you a throne...The throne was given to me by Lord Shiva himself! It is no ordinary throne. Only the greatest of the kings can sit on it. **Any king who sits on the throne would rule for a thousand years**. You have proved to me that you are more than deserving to sit on the throne! I will give the throne to you.'

The throne has 32 puppets with 32 steps. It is said that the puppets were cursed *Apsaras*.

So, the throne made King Vikramaditya to rule for 1000 years. To accompany his Brother Vikramaditya for 1000 years, Bhatti (*a very clever minister*) does worship to **Goddess Kali** to get boon for 2000 years instead of 1000 years. Goddess Kali instructs Bhatti to bring head of his brother Vikramaditya to get the boon. As instructed, Bhatti went to Vikramaditya's room and woke him up (*as killing(unnecessary violence) is sin/Adharma*) and then he states the offer presented by Goddess Kali to him. Vikramaditya without hesitation said to take his head. So, Bhatti did so, he cuts off his head and presented to Goddess Kali in the temple. Happy to see that, Goddess Kali  gave him the boon to live for 2000 years. But Bhatti grinned saying:

> My brother was booned to rule for 1000 years on the throne by lord Indra which was clearly became false by his dead then how can I trust your boon now?

Understanding the cleverness of Bhatti, Goddess Kali granted Bhatti the boon to live for 2000 years and made Vikramaditya alive. She told him to rule for 6 months every year and other 6 months go for tour (*Bhatti explains the trick of why he asked for 2000 years instead of 1000 years to Goddess kali*) <sup>need citation</sup>. So that both the brothers can live for 2000 years. While Vikramaditya was away from the throne, Bhatti used to rule the Kingdom.

There are many stories or adventures related to Vikramaditya which were mostly happened when He was away from the throne for 6 months.

Having said the above, both Vikramaditya as well as Bhatti were great devotees of Goddess Kali. It is said that Vikramaditya used to talk with Goddess Kali frequently in a temple of Ujjain.

Comment: I think it is a sin to kill anyone as it is violence, so unless it is required dharma one should not kill.(as a response to the killing in sleep claim). In this case since Vikramaditya was willingly killing himself for giving his head as a gift to godess this will not be counted as sin. So its better to correct "killing in sleep is sin" line.

Comment: “ Having said the above, both Vikramaditya as well as Bhatti were great devotees of Goddess Kali. It is said that Vikramaditya used to talk with Goddess Kali frequently in a temple of Ujjain.” <—- This is so great ! Thx for posting this 

Answer (score 3):

The story is as follows

When Goddess Kali appeared before Vikramaditya, she blessed him to ‘*rule the country for one thousand years*’! He boasted to his minister Vetala Bhatti about his boon. Wise Bhatti told him that he would make it *2000* years rule. Vikramaditya was surprised to hear it and asked for clarification. Bhatti told him to rule the country for *six months in a year and spend another six months in the forest*. It would double the time of his rule. Vikram was very happy and was ready to follow his advice. But he wanted his minister to stay with him throughout his rule. Bhatti promised that he would also get a boon for 2000 year life span.

Bhatti prayed to Goddess and she appeared before him. When he asked for 2000 year life span, Goddess Kali put a condition, just to avoid Bhatti. She asked Bhatti to cut off the head of Vikram and bring it to her. Bhatti went to Vikram and cut off his head while he was asleep. Vikram knew what happened but did not prevent Bhatti cutting his head off. Vikram had so much trust in his minister that whatever he did was for his good.

Seeing the head of Vikram, Kali kept her promise and blessed Bhatti to live for 2000 years. Immediately Bhatti sniggered at her. Kali was surprised and asked the reason for his laughter. Bhatti said to her, “Oh, I thought you are going to cheat me like you cheated my king Vikram. You gave him a boon to live for 1000 years and look here, I have got his head for you. Kali suddenly realised her ‘mistake’ and brought Vikram to life.

Vikram praised his wise minister Bhatti and both of them ruled for 2000 years. When Vikram was away in the forest for first six months, Bhatti ruled the kingdom. When Bhatti was in the forest, Vikram ruled.

Source : [Vikramaditya](http://tamilandvedas.com/tag/vikramaditya/)

Answer (score 1):

From Source [Vikramaditya](http://tamilandvedas.com/tag/vikramaditya/):

The Godess Kali has given boon to Vikramaditya for ruling 1000 years of his kingdom. Vikramaditya has minister named Bhatti. Bhatti told him that he would make it 2000 years. rule. Bhatti prayed to Goddess and she appeared before him. When he asked for 2000 year life span, Goddess Kali put a condition, just to avoid Bhatti. She asked Bhatti to cut off the head of Vikram and bring it to her. Bhatti went to Vikram and cut off his head while he was asleep. Vikram knew what happened but did not prevent Bhatti cutting his head off. Vikram had so much trust in his minister that whatever he did was for his good.

Seeing the head of Vikram, Kali kept her promise and blessed Bhatti to live for 2000 years. Immediately Bhatti sniggered at her. Kali was surprised and asked the reason for his laughter. Bhatti said to her, “Oh, I thought you are going to cheat me like you cheated my king Vikram. You gave him a boon to live for 1000 years and look here, I have got his head for you. Kali suddenly realised her ‘mistake’ and brought Vikram to life.

This way Vikram praised his wise minister Bhatti and both of them ruled for 2000 years.

Comment: Strange, what I know is that lord Indra gave this boon to him for restoring the money plant in swarg lok and also solving a curious quest of greatest dancer between apsara and rambha. As I know, lord Indra gave boon to Vikramaditya saying that He can rule for 1000 years on the throne he provided to him. (The 32 puppets throne). Well then Bhatti does worship to Goddess Kali to get boon for 2000 years and then later he suggests Vikramaditya to rule for 6 months every year.

Comment: @Mr_Green, I guess different sources, different stories.

Comment: agree with @Kedarnath, however i also heard indra lok story of fight between the upsaras but was not able to find a source for it.

Comment: @SidM To be honest, this post looks wrong to me because asking for boon to live for 1000 years by Vikramaditya seems  so wrong and meaningless. It does mean something if it was offered to Vikramaditya as a token of appreciation by lord Indra. It was the throne which made Vikramaditya to rule for 1000 years not any boon.

Comment: @Mr_Green : May be you are right.. however we do not have any authentic and legitimate source and seeing it now as boon of 1000 years may look meaningless but may be that's what Vikramaditya wanted, hence judging that this is not what Vikramaditya wanted won't be right. Leaving the rest on you, whichever answer you think is right you can mark and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

[@Mr_Green](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2295/3294) [@SidM](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2293/3294) Lord Indra gifted the throne to Vikramaditya and blessed him to rule for 1000 years. However, Vikramaditya's younger brother, Bhatti, could not bear to be separated from him. So, he prayed to Goddess Kali and asked for 2000 years of life, which she granted on one condition.

When Vikramaditya came to know that his brother had been granted 2000 years of life and he had only been granted 1000 years, Bhatti suggested the idea of ruling for 6 months in the palace and 6 months in the forest, which would make 2000 years of rule and allow them to live together.